# Discretization of stochastic continuous-time state-space model

Tags: stochastic-calculus, signal-processing, control-theory

Consider the following stochastic continuous-time state-space model:

$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu $

where $A$ and $B$ are constant matrices, and $u$ is stochastic control input with nonzero mean $\tilde{u}$ and power spectral density $Q$.
If we suppose $u$ has a deterministic part $u^d$ or $\tilde{u}$ and a stochastic part $n$, then we can now construct the following model:

$\dot{x} = Ax + Bu^d + n $

where, now, $n$ is zero mean with power spectral density $Q$.

My question is how one can compute its discrete-time counterpart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally discrete time models are obtained through zero-order hold (assume inputs are constant between time-steps).

The same can be applied to the stochastic input. Using the exact method for time-step $T_s$ we get

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
F & G_u & G_n\\ 
0 & I & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & I
\end{bmatrix} = \exp\left(T_s \begin{bmatrix}
A & B & I\\ 
0 & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}\right) $$

and the discrete model is given by

$$ x_{k+1} = F x_k + G_u u^d_k + G_n n_k $$

Also, note that the power spectral density of $ n $ is not $ Q $, but $ B Q B^T $ (to maintain consistency with previous use of variable) since you removed the B matrix from it.

Comment: To complete discretization, we should compute covariance matrix of $n_k$, $Q_k$. Thank you for answer.